# How to shoot in the same direction my tank is facing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, vector, kivy, kivy-language

I want to shoot a bullet in the direction the tank is facing.  I use Accelerometer to control the angle of my tank. i want my tank to shoot on the direction it is facing as i tilt my device. 
With my current script it only shoots vertically.

To duplicate the problem i couldn't shrink my code than this

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty,ListProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random
import math
from plyer import accelerometer
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Tank>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix

        Rotate:
            angle: self.angle
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
<Flame>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix

        Rotate:
            angle: self.angle
            origin: self.center

    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
<AccelerometerGun>:
    tank: tank
    x_label: x_label
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: "wood.png"
            #texture: root.bg_image.texture#source: "images/bg.png"
            size: self.size#root.size[0]+200, root.size[1]
            pos: self.pos#root.pos
    Label:
        id: x_label
        text: "Tilt value "
        center: self.parent.center
    Tank:
        id: tank
        center: (root.width/2, 70) #self.parent.center
""") 
class Flame(Image):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    active = BooleanProperty(False)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Flame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint=(None, None)
        self.source = "zn.zip"
        self.anim_delay= 0.35
        self.anim_loop = 1
        rs = random.randint(70, 80)
        self.size = (rs, rs)
        self.bind(active=self.addV)
    def addV(self, *args):
        self.velocity_y += random.uniform(20.0, 25.0)
        self.velocity_x += 0
    def move(self, pa):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
        self.angle = random.randint(0, 360)
        self.size = (self.size[0]+1, self.size[1]+1)
        if (self.y > pa.top/1.6):
            pa.removeThis(self)
            self.velocity_y = 0
            self.velocity_x = 0
class Tank(Image):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    activated = BooleanProperty(False)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
    angle = NumericProperty(180)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tank, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'bomb.png'
        self.anim_delay = 0.05
    def move(self, pa):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
        if (self.y < 0-self.size[0]):
            self.velocity_y *= 0
        if (self.x < 0):
            self.velocity_x *= 0
        if (self.right > pa.width):
            self.velocity_x = 0

class AccelerometerGun(Widget):
    tank = ObjectProperty(None)
    angle = NumericProperty(180)
    pr = NumericProperty(0.0)
    flames = []
    def start(self):
        self.tank.center = (self.width/2, 70)
        self.x_label.center = self.center
        self.tank.velocity = 0, 0
        accelerometer.enable()
    def update(self, dt):
        #self.tank.move(self)
        if self.tank.activated:
            val = accelerometer.acceleration[:3]
            if not val == (None, None, None):
                x, y, z = val[0], val[1], val[2]
                self.x_label.text = " ".join(["X", ": " + str(x)])
                self.change(x, y)
        if len(self.flames) != 0:
            for tank in self.flames:
                if tank.active:
                    tank.move(self)

    def change(self, vx, vy):
        max = 2.99
        min = -2.9
        range = max - min
        correctedStartValue = vx - min
        percentage = (correctedStartValue * 180) / range
        if percentage > 180:
            percentage = 180
        if percentage < 0:
            percentage = 0
        if vx == 0.0:
            percentage = 90
        self.tank.angle = percentage
        self.addFlame()
        self.x_label.text = " ".join(["X: ", str(int(vx)),  "%:   ", str(percentage), "Fps: ", str(int(Clock.get_fps()))]) 
        self.tank.velocity_y = 0
        self.tank.velocity_x = 0
        #self.tank.move(self)
    def removeThis(self, bl):
        self.flames.remove(bl)
        self.remove_widget(bl)
        bl = None
    def startFlame(self, *args):
        for tank in self.flames:
            if not tank.active:
                tank.active = True
    def addFlame(self, *args):
        self.fl = Flame()
        self.add_widget(self.fl)
        self.fl.center = self.tank.center
        self.flames.append(self.fl)
        self.fl.velocity = 0, 0
        if len(self.flames) != 0:
            self.startFlame()
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.tank.activated = True

class AccelerometerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = AccelerometerGun()
        game.start()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AccelerometerApp().run()
```

*Note:* i want to move the bullet by using Vector not Animation

Comment: I tried to run your code but got this error: `[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file bomb.png`.  Do I need some of your png files to run your example?

Comment: yeah you should get that error because there is no such image on your device. just rename bomb.png to another image that exists on your computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried solving the question myself.

```
def velX(self, vex):
    for tank in self.flames:
        if tank.active:
            tank.velocity_x = -(vex*2.5) #+= -vel
```

and call it like this

```
def change(self, vx, vy):
    max = 2.99
    min = -2.9
    range = max - min
    correctedStartValue = vx - min
    percentage = (correctedStartValue * 180) / range
    if percentage > 180:
        percentage = 180
    if percentage < 0:
        percentage = 0
    if vx == 0.0:
        percentage = 90
    self.tank.angle = percentage
    self.addFlame()
    self.x_label.text = " ".join(["X: ", str(int(vx)),  "%:   ", str(percentage), "Fps: ", str(int(Clock.get_fps()))]) 
    self.tank.velocity_y = 0 #(vy*-1)*3.5
    self.tank.velocity_x = 0 #(vx*-1)*3.5
    #self.tank.move(self)
    self.velX(vx)
```